# How to get XML data from https url in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, httpsurlconnection, sslhandshakeexception

I want to get XML data from the web server https://ruralfire.qld.gov.au/bushfirealert/bushfireAlert.xml

However, I can't do it because my codes always have an error "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer".

And my InputStream is always null, so I can't do anything with it (such as parsing).

I ensure that the problem is in my connection but I don't know how to solve it.

This is my code in connecting to the web server:

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {

    URL url;
    url = new URL(urlString);

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setDoInput(true);
        is = con.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return is;
}
```

May you help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: InputStream is null because you haven't set con.setDoInput(true);

Comment: Thanh you so much, akhil Rao. After I added setDoInput(true), it still did not work. However, if I changed the url = https://www.google.com , it works well. I thought that this problem relates to SSL.

Comment: What are those two exceptions telling you?

Comment: @greenapps: It said that javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer.

Comment: Which catch block is that?

Comment: I changed another way to solve this problem. Topic closed. Thanks, everyone.